# Where in the Express source is router.get function defined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I wanted to see the implementation of `express.Router.get`.

I looked at the express source on git, starting with the project's `index.js`.

The index has `module.exports = require('./lib/express')`. That file has `var Router = require('./router')`. That location is a directory, so I checked the `index.js` file in that directory. Sure enough it has:

```
var proto = module.exports = function(options) {
  var opts = options || {};

  function router(req, res, next) {
    router.handle(req, res, next);
  }

  // mixin Router class functions
  setPrototypeOf(router, proto)

  router.params = {};
  router._params = [];
  router.caseSensitive = opts.caseSensitive;
  router.mergeParams = opts.mergeParams;
  router.strict = opts.strict;
  router.stack = [];

  return router;
};
```

That's the code that returns the router function. However, there is no `.get` function defined anywhere. Where is the actual function defined?

Note: I'm asking about the `get` function you would use like:
`router.get('/', ...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsing Express v4.15.2 I found the following in `express/lib/application.js` (line 468)

```
/**
 * Delegate `.VERB(...)` calls to `router.VERB(...)`.
 */

methods.forEach(function(method){
  app[method] = function(path){
    if (method === 'get' && arguments.length === 1) {
      // app.get(setting)
      return this.set(path);
    }

    this.lazyrouter();

    var route = this._router.route(path);
    route[method].apply(route, slice.call(arguments, 1));
    return this;
  };
});
```

where `this._router` is coming from `express/lib/router/index.js`

From there depending on what you are looking for you have either:

- `express/lib/router/layer.js::match (line 110)` that checks if this route matches `path`, if so populate `.params`
- `express/lib/router/route.js::dispatch (line 98)` that dispatchs `req, res` to that route

Comment: I can't upvote your answer because I don't have enough reputation, but thanks!